In Wordpress is it necessary to use return; after wp_send_json_error?
After having looked around a bit and not having understood anything I still have the question whether it is necessary to use
return; 
after a wp_send_json_error(); I read that the wp_send_json_error function itself already stops the code execution. So I was wondering why I should use return; after since I know it is a good practice on the web.
I'm just trying wp_send_json_error(); with and without return; after. The code behaves the same, so I'd like to understand more about this.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/ - it doesn't appear to a return a value, so adding a return does nothing except kick it out of the function.

if you send JSON, the good practice is to extend the API in your plugin : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/. then mostly, you will no more use wp_send_json_error and wp_send_json.

The why is because wp_send_json_error() function source code includes wp_send_json() which includes die(), so return; is neither needed nor recommended.
